# R- rename multiple .txt files with a certain pattern

Tags: r, file-rename

I have txt files with names shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyXmQ.png), from A to L, exvey letter has 1-24 as suffix, totally 12*24=288 files.

Take ACE Group as example: A1, C1 and E1 are 3 repeats of the same sample. To process the 3 repeat together. So I want to rename the files by adding prefix numbers, as shown in [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFLUm.png), the prefix are regular but not continuous.

The BDF, GIL and HJK Group should be renamed with the same pattern as ACE. Each group of files saves in seperate folder named as "ACE", "BDF"...

I try to creat a namelist with `paste()` and rename with `lapply()`:

```
paste0(seq(1,70,3),rep("A",1), rep(seq(1,24,1),1))
```

But this code gives me a list with "1A1" rather than "01A1". Also, I don't know how to extracting of capital letter from old name. It's not efficent changing capital letter in code every run.

How can I do the rename?

Comment: Use `sprintf("%02d", seq(1,70,3))` to prepend 0s to your digits until it has length 2

Comment: paste0(sprintf("%02d", seq(1,70,3)),rep("A",1), rep(seq(1,24,1),1)) . This works, thank you.